# Android check value and redraw menu

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to display and hide navigation drawer menu items depending on the value of a variable. The start of my class looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public boolean subCreated = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Highlight the MainActivity (as default) on start
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_new);

        //Hide participant specific menu items
        if(subCreated == false){
            navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_start).setVisible(false);
            navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_delete).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_start).setVisible(true);
            navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_delete).setVisible(true);
        }

    }
...
```

`subCreated` is initially set to false on app launch. In the `onCreate` method I'm checking the value of `subCreated`. If it is false, hide 2 menu items, otherwise, display them.

I'm setting the value of `subCreated` when the user selects a particular menu item:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_new:
                subCreated = true;
                break;
...
```

The initially hidden menu items dont display when the user clicks the menu item. I'm guessing its because the check is only performed when the app is first launched. Whats the correct way to check the value of a variable and then perform an action (show a menu item) depending on the value?

I realize I can achieve this functionality by just showing/hiding the items right within `onNavigationItemSelected()`. But I'm trying to achieve this with static/instance variables as I'm treating it somewhat like a session variable that I can check in other methods for other (menu unrelated) functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On suggestion for you. You can try with method:

```
private void showSub(boolean flag) {

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
    if (!flag) {
        navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_start).setVisible(false);
        navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_delete).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_start).setVisible(true);
        navMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_delete).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and onCreate():

```
//Hide participant specific menu items
    if(subCreated == false){
        showSub(false);
    } else {
        showSub(true);
    }
```

and onNavigationItemSelected():

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_new:
            subCreated = true;
            showSub(true);
            break;
...
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: I thought about doing it this way but the reason why I ask about setting and checking a variable is because I'm treating that like a session variable that is persistent across the session that I can reference with other methods for other functionality as well. Is there a way to do this with setting a static/instance variable in the main class as well?

Comment: You want to use a variable to control the show/hide item menu, and want to save this variable somewhere to use? If true, you can save to Preference, then can get/change this  value anywhere.

Comment: Yes that sounds right. What would be the code to implement preferences in the context of a nav menu like this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you can use SharePreference than Preference. Many documents and samples how to use SharePreference, you can find one to  implement.